# Attribute error when trying to import scipy.interpolate

Tags: python, scipy, python-import

I am trying to import `scipy.interpolate` using the following code:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
```

but I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: scipy.spatial.qhull is deprecated and has no attribute __pyx_capi__. Try looking in scipy.spatial instead.
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: The import statement `from scipy.interpolate import interp1d` worked for me. No errors. I am using scipy version 1.10.0. What version of scipy are you on?

Comment: @VandanRevanur I am on scipy version `1.9.3`.

Comment: Maybe try upgrading.